# iOS: Images slide show

Tags: ios, imageview, xcode5

Here is my code of slide show of images:

```
-(void)setImage
{
     imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrImages objectAtIndex:0]];
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)changeImage
{

   imageId = imageId + 1;

   int id = imageId % [arrImages count];
   CATransition * trs = [CATransition animation];
   trs.duration = 0.5;
   [trs setType:kCATransitionPush];
   imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrImages objectAtIndex:id]];
   [imageView.layer addAnimation:trs forKey:kCATransition];
}
```

i am calling setImage() method on button click.

first time when i am clicking on button it works fine but after that whenever i click on button,  speed of slideshow increases.

Can any one tell me why this happens.

Thanx.

Comment: Oviouslly its increases, coz every time u call that method on your click action. so when u click that time u have to check if its running then stop the animation and start again.

Comment: first u invalid/stop that animation and again start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take globally a timer.

```
 NSTimer *timer;

 -(void)setImage
 {
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrImages objectAtIndex:0]];
    if (timer)
    {
      [timer invalidate];
      timer = nil;
    }

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }
```

Try this one :)